# Odoo 10 : Open XML view from a button

Tags: python, odoo-10

I searched a lot to find an easy example to follow since I'm a newbie and this is my first module I'm working on. All the example I have found are a little bit hard to understand or not respond to my need.

I have 3 models :
Product
Package
Product_package (I need to keep this one as a dependent table according to my project db conception)

I need to create a product_package from the product view.

I tried in the views/product.xml page :

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="product_form_view">
        <field name="name">product.form</field>
        <field name="model">tjara.product</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Produit Form">
                <head>
                   <button name="%(product_package_list_action2)d" type='action' string='Ajouter Emballage'/>
                </head>
                <sheet>
                    <group>
                        <field name="name"/>
                        <field name="add_date"/>
                    </group>
                    <notebook>
                        <page string="Description">
                            <label for="description" string="Fiche du produit"/>
                            <field name="description"/>
                        </page>
                        <page string="Fournisseurs">
                            <label for="provider_ids"/>
                            <field name="provider_ids"/>
                        </page>
                        <page string="Clients">
                            <label for="client_ids"/>
                            <field name="client_ids"/>
                        </page>
                    </notebook>

                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

And in the same page I added :

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="product_package_list_action2">
        <field name="name">Emballages</field>
        <field name="res_model">tjara.product_package</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="product_package_form_view"/>
    </record>
```

Any one has a solution to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found a solution.

This is the button in the product Xml page :

```
                    <header>
                         <button name="%(product_package_list_action2)d" type='action' string='Ajouter Emballage'/>
                    </header>
```

In the same page I insert the following :

```
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="product_package_list_action2">
        <field name="name">Emballages</field>
        <field name="res_model">tjara.product_package</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="product_package_form_view"/>
    </record>
```

In the product_price Xml page I have this code :

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="product_package_form_view">
        <field name="name">product_package.form</field>
        <field name="model">tjara.product_package</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Emballage Form">
                <sheet>
                    <group>
                        <field name="product_id"/>
                        <field name="package_id"/>
                        <field name="price"/>
                    </group>
                    <notebook>
                        <page string="Description">
                            <field name="description"/>
                        </page>
                    </notebook>

                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

And in the manifest I load the product_package before the product Xml. This solve my problem despite I get a full page instead a pop up window.